# Regex for directive on Number

Tags: regex, angular

I have a directive for input on angular app.

I´m building a regex for accepting:

- 1,2,3.2
- 1222,23
- 333333

Not accepting:

- 1,,333
- 132,.1
- -123

I have to check char by char, which that I´m not putting a whole number in input. My try that not work.

```
^[,]{0,1}\d{0,10}[,]{0,1}([.]?\d{0,2})
```

Comment: Is that a single number or a comma-separated list of numbers?

Comment: it´s a single number. 1,2,3.2 = 123.2

Comment: Try `^\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  or this is very good. How can I define just 3 decimal and 5 integers as example?

Comment: Maybe `^(?!(?:,?\d){6})\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d{1,3})?$`

Answer (score 1):

In the most general case you may use

```
^\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?$ // 432 or 4.653 or 1,44,43211 or 1,4456,43211754.876597
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uhgkE5/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%2B)*(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B)%3F%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:,\d+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of `,` and 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - 1 or 0 repetitions of `.` and 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Use limiting quantifiers and lookaheads to impose length restrictions. For example:

```
^(?!(?:,?\d){6})\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d{1,3})?$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?!(?:,?\d){6})` negative lookahead will fail the match if there are 6 or more digits in the integer part of the number. If you want to restrict the whole number length change the lookahead to `(?!.{6})` and it will only match numbers up to 5 chars: `1`, `1.55`, `35.99` but not `100.12` (=6 chars).